# Таймер обратного отсчета

Tags: c#, таймер

Добрый день. Нужен совет по реализации таймера обратного отсчета на C#. мне отдается время в секундах, его нужно нужно перевести в формат минуты:секунды и реализовать отсчет времени назад на текст-боксе. при остановке таймера или при окончании времени нужно перевести время назад в секунды. Делаю так:

```
int sec, min;
DateTime limitTime = new DateTime(0, 0);
  limitTime = limitTime.AddSeconds(LimitSecondsPerDay);
  min = limitTime.Minute;
  sec = limitTime.Second;
  tbLimitTime.Text = min + ":" + sec;

private void tServiceTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        tbLimitTime.Text = min + ":" + sec;

        if (min == 0 && sec == 0)
        {
            tServiceTimer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("time is over");
        }
        else
            if (sec == 0)
            { sec = 60; min--; }
        sec--;
    }
```

Вопрос: как переконвертировать время назад в секунды и можно ли реализовать такую работу таймера более правильно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Я бы рекомендовал Вам использовать класc TimeSpan, который описывает интервал времени. Внутри он использует очень мелкие единицы, но его можно переводить в дни, часы, минуты, секунды и т.п.
2. Отнимать секунды только по таймеру не очень правильно - точность вызова функции не высока. За большой период времени набежит большая погрешность. Правильно запоминать начальный или конечный момент и отталкиваться от него.

Ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
//запоминаем последний момент
DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(LimitSecondsPerDay);
  tbLimitTime.Text = TimeLeft().ToString();

//возвращает сколько времени осталось до конца
private TimeSpan TimeLeft()
{
    return end - DateTime.Now;
}

private void tServiceTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        tbLimitTime.Text = TimeLeft.ToString();

        if (TimeLeft < TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            tServiceTimer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("time is over");
        }
    }
```